# What is the actual trigger of motherboard debug LEDs?

Tags: led, debugging, firmware, motherboard, boot-configure

I am aware that when one remains lit, it is indicative of the part of my system that can't be initialized; it's helped me with several builds. However, I can't help but notice that even in a perfectly healthy and functional build, such as I produced today, they flicker quite a bit during the initial power-on process. I imagine it may be the same for many other brands.

My question is, since it clearly doesn't necessarily relate to a bad or mis-seated component if it's not persistent, what is it that causes these LEDs to turn on? If I had to guess, I'd say that it's the phase of detection that the firmware is in—CPU for detecting the CPU, DDR for initializing the RAM, etc.—and it remains in that state if the component can't be properly initialized. However, I hate guessing when I can ask relative experts.

What actual condition turns on the debug LEDs?

**EDIT**: There seems to be a significant misreading of this question, which has resulted in it being closed.

I am not asking about the usage of the motherboard, but for a clarification about the principle behind its design. I can and do use it just fine. So this isn't a "use" instead of "design" question.

Moreover, the Debug LEDs (present on most modern motherboards) are clearly beneath the level of the motherboard's firmware, as, as far as I know, you can't hack them or repurpose them easily; so it seems extremely unlikely that anyone on Superuser will be able to help, aside from directing me to the documentation; which is scant and I have already read several times.

Moreover, the documentation, as I felt I already explained, is incomplete and inconsistent with the end experience—happens to the best of us—and my hope is that a motherboard designer somewhere on this particular stack will know what the actual design and trigger of the LEDs is, and can clarify why this documentation is true. I am asking for the design pattern, not a how-to.

Comment: Is this actually a question about electrical engineering? This sounds more like a question for Superuser.

Comment: what are `MSI's EZ Debug LEDs`? ... refer to the device user manual or the device datasheet

Comment: @jsotola The device manual is incomplete and inconsistent with the end experience, or I wouldn't be here.

Comment: @Hearth Is it possible to move it to Superuser somehow? I can copy-paste, but Stack Exchange usually has something more elegant.

Comment: @MichaelMacha I voted to move it, but I was outvoted by two people who wanted to just close it. I believe a moderator could move it.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately this isn't much easier of a question to answer -- the only people who know for sure are those who designed the motherboard. Possibly schematics, or firmware (does it use an onboard microcontroller to monitor booting?) are available somewhere, in which case that would answer your question. In lieu of these, answers will likely be opinion-based. Finally, you could try asking more directly along those lines: "how would you [design a motherboard to do the same thing]?" But still, I think there aren't many people working with M.B. HW who would know, so -- it's not easy.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you, Tim, it seemed it was worthy of a shot.

Comment: But you are really asking how some random LEDs on a random motherboard work, or how they are made to work. They are controllwd by firmware, or hardware, based on some conditions. And I don't mean BIOS running on you CPU, they can be controlled by some embedded system controller in the chipset. There is no way anyone can tell you how it is possible to design in such LEDs into a motherboard, unless you are talking to the engineer that made them work. The question can be generalized how can any LED on any product signal the things they do.

Comment: @Justme I can certainly generalize the question to debug LEDs. They're present on most modern motherboards. However, since the last three mobos I've worked on have been MSIs (incidentally), I thought that specifics might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the example of the [EZ Debug LEDs](https://www.msi.com/support/technical_details/MB_Boot_No_Display) and taking a guess, I'd say the simplest way to explain what goes on is as follows:

1. There's an IC or a part of the CPU chipset that controls the LEDs.
2. At power on, the LED controller turns on the CPU LED.
3. The firmware turns off the CPU LED when it starts running.  If the CPU isn't there or doesn't run, the LED stays on because the CPU is what runs the firmware.
4. For each of the other LEDs (DRAM, VGA, BOOT) the firmware turns on the LED then tests the component.
5. If the test succeeds, the firmware turns off the LED.
6. If the test fails or there's a drastic error that causes the firmware to hang, the LED stays on.
7. There may be several tests that apply to each component, with the "turn on, test, turn off" cycle repeating for each test for each component.

That would explain the flickering you see during power on.

There's probably other ways it could be done, but I think that's the simplest explanation.

---

The LEDs probably could be accessed from the operating system if the manufacturer were to provide a driver (MS Windows) or if someone could dig through all the available devices on the system and reverse engineer the addresses and commands (Linux or MS Windows.)

There's probably nobody trying because the LEDs aren't exactly in a useful place.  They are only useful when the case is open and you can see them in their little hiding place.

Comment: This makes sense to me and matches my experience, I'm going to accept it as an answer. It would be great if anyone ever has a reference or specification to show it from a company's designs, though!